# Sort a vector containing only three distinct values

Tags: c++, performance, sorting

I have a program that sorts the vector containing only 0,1,2 in the sequential order so the input array of `[0,2,1,2,1]` would generate an output `[0,1,1,2,2]`.

Following is the functional code however I feel like considering the input `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1]`, `i` and `left` are being iterated over the same elements and I feel we could reduce the iteration to one. I thought of setting `i` to `left` as long as `left > i` but I ended up running into an infinite loop (where left and right would keep `i` not get past the finish line).

Any ways to improve it?

```
    void SortNums(vector<int>& nums) 
    { 
        int right = nums.size()-1;
        int left = 0;

        for (int i=0; i < nums.size() && left < right; i++)
        {
            while (left < right && nums[left] == 0) left++;
            while (left < right && nums[right] == 2) right--;
            
            if (left >= right) break;
            
            if (i > left && nums[i] == 0) 
            {
                std::swap(nums[left], nums[i--]);
            }
            if (i < right && nums[i] == 2)
            {
                std::swap(nums[i--], nums[right]);
            }
        }   
   }
```

Comment: Is there some reason you can't use `std::sort()` (or `std::ranges::sort()`) from the `<algorithm>` library?  Or are you intentionally [tag:reinventing-the-wheel]?

Comment: And is `vector` here an alias of `std::vector`, or something else?  You'll get better reviews if you provide code that's complete, with the necessary headers or other definitions for it to compile.

Comment: Have you considered [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort)?  With only 3 distinct values, you can turn large arrays into a very compact histogram, which you can expand back into a sorted array if you want.  If the 3 values are in a small known range, you can index an array of counts, otherwise `switch` or if/else if/else.  (I'd recommend against a std::unordered_map hash table for only 3 elements.)  See [Micro Optimization of a 4-bucket histogram of a large array or list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61122144) for how to count very fast with SIMD for 32-bit elements.

Comment: @TobySpeight it's `std::vector`. And I am "reinventing the wheel" if you want to put it that way.

Answer (score 6):

> however I feel like considering the input [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,2,1], i and left are being iterated over the same elements

```
            while (left < right && nums[left] == 0) left++;
            while (left < right && nums[right] == 2) right--;
```

Those are some interesting hard-coded
[magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)).

The code doesn't spell
out that the acceptable domain of input values
is {0, 1, 2}, yet that is the operative assumption.
I would find this code easier to read
(e.g. identifiers like `SortNums`)
if it described the use case for focusing on small integers.
As it is, "num" and "int" suggests a much larger range.

---

Let us be explicit that the input values shall
be integers ranging from 0 .. K.
And the output shall be a sorted copy of the input.

Then an O(N log N) algorithm is a fool's game,
when we can play to win!
Use [radix sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radix_sort)
to solve it in O(N) time complexity and
(at worst) O(K) space complexity,
with K << N typically.

Here, allocate K counters, and make a linear pass
over the input, incrementing the appropriate counter
for each value.
Then the output phase is simple.
For the `i`-th counter, output a bunch of `i` values.

---

In short you are solving a restricted problem,
which does not encompass what the general "sort" literature tackles.

Comment: I was clear in the description that the vector would only contain 0,1,2. Not sure what wasn't clear about the acceptable domain of input values...

Comment: @xyf you were clear about that in the post you created on codereview.stackexchange.com... but nowhere in your code do you actually document that. That's all that J_H has suggested you should do: your function's signature and documentation (and implementation) should make it obvious to readers of _your code_, and users of your function's public API _while coding_, what it does.

Comment: This sounds more like counting sort, no?

Comment: @Rdp You're right, although J_H is sort of correct since often radix sort will use counting sort to sort each digit, so if your input only consists of numbers of one digit it is the same as counting sort.

Comment: @theonlygusti I mean...were you expecting me to write doxygen briefs as to what parameter the function should hold, and what should it return? I thought you could specify the requirements and I think I did that already. Pretty sure I can find a lot of posts on here that don't provide documentation of the code itself or at least I wasn't aware that's a *requirement* to post here. And as an answer, I would expect a functional code snippet.

Comment: An array of K counters is [Counting Sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort).  Radix Sort is when you make multiple passes using a range of bits to divide into buckets, e.g. group based on top 8 bits, then within those buckets group based on the next-lowest 8 bits.  Counting Sort is sort of a special case of Radix Sort where you use the whole number to index a bucket, but unlike Radix Sort (@G.Sliepen) there are no other bits to record so you can just count instead of growing a list.

Comment: @xyf Your question is actually fine and a good question, but maybe you have unreasonable expectations of this site. Answerers have gone out of their way to give you a _code review_: recommending that your source code clarifies acceptable inputs is a code review. I think it shouldn't matter whether feedback that can help you is in the form of written prose or code examples, sometimes writing is even more appropriate. Why do you not value answers that are not working blocks of code?

Answer (score 6):

#### Provide self-contained code

You are missing headers, and namespaces:

```cpp
#include <utility>
#include <vector>

void SortNums(std::vector<int>& nums) {
    ...
}
```

#### Compile with warnings

On Clang and GCC, this means `-Wall -Wextra -Werror`.

#### Ensure correct integer types

The size of a `std::vector` is `std::size_t`, an unsigned integer, not `int`.

The indexes which you use to index over `std::vector` should also be `std::size_t`.

*Note: comparisons between signed and unsigned integers can give weird results, the compiler would have warned about this.*

#### Switch to a better type (C++20)

In the end, you never manipulate the vector size, or capacity. In fact, your function would work on any slice of `int`, regardless of whether they're from an array, a `vector`, or something else.

From C++20 onwards, you should use `std::span<int>` as an argument, instead.

#### Cache the vector size

The compiler may or may not be able to optimize `nums.size()`. It'll depend whether it manages to prove that the writes performed through `nums[...]` may or may not alter the size.

It's thus best practice to cache the size (or end iterator) when doing such iteration.

```cpp
for (std::size_t i = 0, max = nums.size(); i < max && left < right; ++i) {
}
```

#### Use pre-increment

Use pre-increment when post-increment is unnecessary. While in practice for integral types the generated code will be the same, for complex iterators this is not the case, thus it's a good habit to get into.

#### Always wrap blocks with brackets

Always use brackets around blocks after a `while`, `if`, etc...

Apple's GOTO FAIL bug would have been easier to spot with the proper use of brackets, for example.

#### Use a better algorithm

Having a limited number of values is the text-book usecase for Counting Sort.

Assuming that we are specializing for `[0, 2]`, this means:

```cpp
#include <cassert>

#include <algorithm>
#include <span>
#include <utility>

void SortNums(std::span<int> nums) {
    //  The best way to document pre-conditions, is to enforce them.
    assert(std::all_of(nums.begin(), nums.end(),
        [](int i) { return 0 <= i && i <= 2; });

    std::size_t counts[3] = { 0, 0, 0 };

    for (auto i : nums) { ++counts[i]; }

    auto it = nums.begin();
    for (int i = 0; i < 3; ++i) {
        it = std::fill_n(it, counts[i], i);
    }
}
```

This algorithm has O(N) time complexity (two linear passes over the data) and O(1) extra space complexity.

It also likely triggers auto-vectorization of the write pass, and may trigger auto-vectorization of the read pass.

Comment: That's https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Counting_sort not Radix Sort, as discussed in comments under J_H's answer.  Re: choice of var name: I'd avoid `i` for the loop over `nums`, e.g. `for (auto num : nums) { ++counts[num]; }`.  Normally `i` is a loop counter for counted loops, not an arbitrary integer loaded from another array.

Comment: Please do not edit the question, especially the code, after an answer has been posted. Changing the question may cause answer invalidation. Everyone needs to be able to see what the reviewer was referring to. [What to do after the question has been answered](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Comment: @pacmaninbw: I think you meant to comment under the question, not this answer.

Comment: For high-performance histogramming of a very small number of unique values, see See [Micro Optimization of a 4-bucket histogram of a large array or list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/61122144) for how to count very fast with SIMD for 32-bit elements, in that case C++ with AVX2.  With two pcmpeq/psubd in the loop to count 0s and 1s, you can derive the count for `2` from `size - ones - zeros`; Zen 2 or Ice Lake could potentially handle 8 ints per clock cycle.

Comment: For highly-redundant data like a large array of 3 unique values, a compact data structure like a 3-entry histogram is often usable instead of a sorted array, so I'd recommend making that available as an output of this function, or split to multiple functions so you can just histogram without wasting time expanding again.

Comment: Can you please walk through your algo and how it's better than mines in terms of efficiency specially the iterative part?

Comment: @xyf: Yours has a bunch of data-dependent branching, which is relatively slow on modern high-performance CPUs compared to loads/stores that hit in L1d cache.  Some CPUs (Zen 2 and Zen 4, and Ice Lake) can even remove the store/reload forwarding latency bottleneck of a standard scalar histogram incrementing the same memory location multiple times in a row, by optimizing store-forwarding for the same address (accessed with the same addressing-mode).    https://www.agner.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=41 / https://chipsandcheese.com/2022/11/08/amds-zen-4-part-2-memory-subsystem-and-conclusion/

Comment: And histogramming can be optimized much further with SIMD when there are only 3 unique values.  (But not when there are many more; then you'd just use memory and SIMD doesn't help you.)  You can optimize the standard histogram algorithm with small numbers of buckets by unrolling over multiple arrays of counts (which you combine at the end, cheaply with SIMD) to hide those store/reload bottlenecks.

Comment: @xyf: Anyway, your algorithm is interesting and might win on a low-end CPU like ARM Cortex-M3 or something (short pipeline so cheap branching, and only running 1 instruction at a time in-order).  Or maybe an old x86 CPU like 486 or Pentium.  But counting is fast, and `memset` / `std::fill` tends to be highly optimized to run faster than 1 element at a time, e.g. filling 32 bytes at a time.  Also, if you don't do that step, you have your data in a much more compact representation that can be used for various things, like prefix-summed so indexing the original data is just a matter of bsearch.

Comment: Since C++11, we can replace the `std::fill` and `it +=` with a simple `it = std::fill_n(it, counts[i], i)`, since that function now returns the iterator immediately following the written values (and does the right thing if the count is zero).

Comment: It might be better to avoid your debug builds doing an extra pass over the input - and simultaneously reduce the Magic Number count: `for (auto i: nums) { assert(static_cast<unsigned>(i) < sizeof counts); }`  (there's a sneaky implicit `i >=0` hidden there, which warrants a comment). Or use a standard library array, giving us `std::array::at()` for the debug build.

Comment: @Peter, I have [answered](/a/283372/75307) with a suggestion to just return a histogram object - is that the approach you're recommending?

Comment: @TobySpeight: Yeah.  And have a separate function to expand that into an array in case you need that.

Answer (score 3):

Consider a drastic change of interface - instead of sorting elements in-place, it might be better to return a histogram object with vector-like access:

```
histogram sorted(const std::input_range& auto nums);
```

We could implement the `histogram` as

```
#include <iterator>
#include <numeric>
#include <ranges>

// Special case histogram class that counts values that are 0, 1 or 2.
class histogram_012
{
    std::array<std::size_t,3> count{{ 0, 0, 0 }};

public:
    struct const_iterator
    {
        using difference_type = std::ptrdiff_t;
        using value_type = int;
        using pointer = int*;
        using reference = int&;
        using iterator_category = std::input_iterator_tag;

        const histogram_012 *p;
        std::size_t pos;

        constexpr auto operator<=>(const const_iterator& other) const = default;

        const_iterator& operator++()
        {
            ++pos; return *this;
        }

        auto operator*() const
        {
            // This is just for exposition; it's not efficient
            auto n = pos;
            int  i = 0;
            for (auto c: p->count) {
                if (n < c) { return i; }
                n -= c;
                ++i;
            }
            // out-of-range (undefined)
            return 0;
        }
    };

    template<std::ranges::input_range C>
    requires std::is_same_v<int, std::ranges::range_value_t<C>>
    explicit constexpr histogram_012(C const& nums)
    {
        std::size_t total = 0;
        for (int n: nums) {
            count[0] += (n == 0);
            count[1] += (n == 1);
            ++total;
        }
        count[2] = total - count[0] - count[1];
    }

    // Minimal container interface - this needs completing
    constexpr auto size() const { return std::accumulate(count.begin(), count.end(), std::size_t{}); }
    constexpr const_iterator begin() const { return {this, 0}; }
    constexpr const_iterator end() const { return {this, size()}; }
};
```

and `sorted()` as

```
constexpr auto sorted(auto const& nums) { return histogram_012{nums}; }
```

Simple demo:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <vector>
int main()
{
    std::vector<int> values = {0,2,1,2,1};
    auto const sorted_values = sorted(values);
    std::copy(sorted_values.begin(), sorted_values.end(),
              std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, ", "));
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Credit to [Peter Cordes](/users/50567) for suggesting this approach, in comments to other answers.

An exercise for the interested reader is to create a generalised version that histograms a fixed set of values of a given type, i.e.

```
template<std::equality_comparable T, T... values> class histogram
```

Comment: For 3 distinct values, using a simple array of counters is a nice approach. It doesn't scale well, though, as the "random access" property is lost for larger Ns, but that can be recovered by switching to a Fenwick Tree -- my favorite exotic data-structure -- which can give O(log N) read/write.

Comment: Nice idea to have iterators for it that work like the expanded array; you'd also want direct access to the histogram and/or a prefix-sum for algorithms that can be tweaked to deal with that. I'd been picturing returning that for direct use by callers that could be adapted for it.  You'd probably also want to provide a function that can `std::fill` the histogram back into a sorted array, for any callers you haven't specialized for histograms and which can't use `operator*`.

Comment: The count loop can be optimized to only count `0` and `1` elements, with `count[2] = nums.size() - count[0] - count[1]` after the loop.

Comment: Yes, although `nums.size()` doesn't necessarily exist for a `std::ranges::input_range` - but we could overload that constructor for `std::ranges::sized_range`, or just maintain a count as we loop.

Comment: Yes, I realised that afterwards @G.Sliepen.  Now fixed.  Don't need to find a counter for the `T` I think, because we naturally have the index that as we test each value.

Comment: I think this will involve `std::index_sequence<values...>` but haven't actually implemented it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I agree with the others that it would be best to just count the number of zeros, ones, and twos, and then to fill the vector accordingly. However, you asked how to simplify your loop, so I will present a solution that is similar in spirit to yours. My goal is to show how to reason about a loop like this and to ensure correctness (and termination, i.e. not to run into an infinite loop): Write down the invariants and ensure that you keep them and also make progress for each iteration.

```cpp
    void SortNums(vector<int>& nums) 
    { 
        std::size_t right = nums.size();
        std::size_t left = 0;
        std::size_t i = 0;

        // We will keep these invariants all through the function
        // (with N = nums.size()):
        //     0 <= left <= i <= right <= N
        //     nums[k] == 0   for 0 <= k < left
        //     nums[k] == 1   for left <= k < i
        //     nums[k] == 2   for right <= k < N
        // The array will be sorted when  i == right.

        while (i < right)  // each iteration decreases right-i by 1
        {
            switch (nums[i])
            {
            case 0:
                // If  left == i, then we just need to increase
                // left and i.
                // If  left < i, then nums[left] == 1 and we want
                //    nums[left++] = 0;
                //    nums[i++] = 1;
                // The following works in both cases.
                std::swap(nums[left++], nums[i++]);
                break;
            case 1:
                ++i;
                break;
            case 2:
                std::swap(nums[i], nums[--right]);
                break;
            default:
                throw std::logic_error(
                    "element not 0,1,2 in SortNums");
            }
        }   
   }
```

As indicated in the comment, there will be exactly `sums.size()` iterations of the loop.

Regarding some style details, I don't know whether I would use pre-/post-increments in expressions, but you did, so I kept to that style.
I have changed the index variables from `int` to `size_t`. There is an argument to be made for signed index variables, but `int` might not be large enough. Note that having unsigned index variable, I had to avoid `- 1`, so my `right` differs from yours by one. But I would have wanted that anyways, because now all of the intervals in the invariants are of the form `... <= k < ...` as is customary.
One could also use iterators instead of indexes, it is a matter of taste:

```cpp
    auto left = nums.begin();
    auto right = nuts.end();
    auto it = left;
```

The comment in `case 0` shows that there are some unnecessary reads of `nums[left]` there. One could optimise that but it would be at the expense of brevity, so I thought that it would be besides the point.

Comment: Aren't you doing unnecessary swaps? if the input is `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,1]`, you'd be swapping all the 0s for no real purpose

Comment: @xyf yes, that's what my last sentence was about. One could optimize this, but that would only be an improvement for certain inputs. If you add a 1 to the beginning of your example you need to do those swaps anyway.

Comment: You wouldn't need to do that many swaps, though, if you think beyond Bubble Sort logic for getting a `1` to the other side of a long run of `0`s.  If you scan until a non-zero, you can swap the `1` with the last `0`, leaving the intervening `0`s in place.  (If compilers were smarter, checking 16 or 32 bytes at a time for the first non-zero element with AVX2 could go *much* faster than swapping; with real compilers only somewhat faster.)  If that idea only helps at the very start of the array, it might be worth leaving it out if you know that tends not to happen in your real data.  (@xyf)

Answer (score 0):

One way to optimize the implementation is to avoid iterating over the same elements multiple times. Here's a modified implementation that uses only one loop:

```
void SortNums(vector<int>& nums) 
{ 
    int left = 0, right = nums.size()-1, i = 0;
    
    while (i <= right)
    {
        if (nums[i] == 0)
        {
            std::swap(nums[i], nums[left]);
            left++;
            i++;
        }
        else if (nums[i] == 2)
        {
            std::swap(nums[i], nums[right]);
            right--;
        }
        else
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: So you agree with my answer :)